# undefined property accessing attribute in twig

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

What is the correct way to  access attributes of my 'userEntity' object.

```
{{ userEntities[1].jobs.id }}
```

gives the error

> Undefined property: Baker\TimeSlipBundle\Entity\UserDetails::$Jobs

dumping `{{ dump(userEntities[1] }}` gives me.

```
UserDetails {#526 ▼
  -jobs: Jobs {#520 ▼
    #clients: null
    #company: null
    #scopes: PersistentCollection {#597 ▶}
    #workHours: PersistentCollection {#599 ▶}
    #userDetails: PersistentCollection {#601 ▶}
    -id: 52
    -description: "From Web"
    -jobNumber: "344.00"
    -task: null
    -currencies: null
    -active: 0
  }
  -user: User {#524 ▶}
  -id: 9
  -userrate: "2300"
  -position: "m"
}
```

also calling    `{{ userEntities[1].id }}` works as it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check what is jobs property name in your Entity class (Baker\TimeSlipBundle\Entity\UserDetails.php)

Comment: your right, my issue was a wrong case on the getJobs getter. Thanks, i had assumed it was correct as i used the entity generator to create it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a getter method in UserDetails class for "jobs" attribute

Comment: If the `getJobs()` method doesn't exist, we would get a 'Call to undefined method getJobs()' , and if `$jobs` property doesn't exist, we would get `Undefined property Entity::$jobs` , but we get  `Entity::$Jobs ` , surely a schema error

Comment: try this {% set job = userEntities[1].jobs %} then {{ job.id }}

Comment: issue was with the getter method, like u said. It was there but, there not generated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your error said `UserDetails::$Jobs` , in twig you call `userEntities[1].jobs.id`, and your dump retur property `$jobs` for entity `Jobs`.

So, your error should be : `Undefined property: Baker\TimeSlipBundle\Entity\UserDetails::$jobs`and not `$Jobs`. Be careful when you name your relation properties. `$jobs` suggests a `userEntities` (should be `UserDetail` instead of `UserDetails` too ...) can have many `jobs`, except that your dump show `a userEntities` can have only one `$jobs`.
 It is confusing.

I can not see your mapping for moment, but I think it's your
`UserDetails::$jobs` association mappedBy option:

It must be equal to `mappedBy="jobs"`, but surely currently equal to `"mappedBy=Jobs"`.

Please show your two entities with mapping for associations.